# Magento: why the empty tables do have weight?

Tags: mysql, database, magento

Why do database empty tables with 0 rows have the weight?

Also there are other empty tables with 0 weight. 
What is the difference?

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQllC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I'd say 16KiB is the minimum size that will be allocated for a table on disk. It still has to use some data to store information about the table like its name and structure.

The table with zero size looks like it might be a temporary table or something, which might exist only in memory and be using a different engine, which perhaps doesn't report this information as it would have to be kept in memory anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I examined the engine type, and found that all the tables 16KiB have InnoDB type, the 0 B - has MEMORY engine.

Comment: And also there are InnoDB tables with several rows (for ex, 1-4), that also have 16KiB. It seems that InniDB table has at least 16 Kib - the structure has weight, even if there is no information at all. I want to look at MyISAM empty tables, but I havn't found it in the database.